# How can I simplify and make this more elegant?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following is used to create a masonry effect with varying height rectangles. How can I simplify and make this more elegant?

```
private float startX = 0.0f;
private float startY = 0.0f;
private float posX = 0.0f;
private float posY = 0.0f;
private float prevWidth = 0;
private float prevHeight = 0;
private int index = 0;
private int currentCol = 0;


private void AddCard(int index, int col, float width, float height)
{
    GameObject goCard = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(pfCard00);
    PackedSprite psCard = goCard.GetComponentInChildren<PackedSprite>();

    goCard.name = "QuestItemCard" + index.ToString();
    goCard.transform.parent = goCardContainer.transform;
    psCard.height = height;

    if (currentCol != col) 
    {
        posX += width;

        posY = 0;
        prevHeight = 0;
    }

    // placement
    posY += (prevHeight / 2) + (height / 2);
    goCard.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(startX + posX, startY - posY, goCard.transform.position.z);

    if (currentCol != col)
    {
        prevWidth = width;

        currentCol = col;
    }

    prevHeight = height;
}
```

Usage:

```
AddCard(0, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(1, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(2, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(3, 0, 100, 200);

AddCard(0, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(1, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(2, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(3, 1, 100, 200);
```

Comment: So do you have a problem with the method itself, or how it's called?  Also note that since you don't have a specific problem, this probably belongs on codereivew, not SO.

Comment: Is there a way to move this to there?

Comment: Your question is more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about beautifying code which is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips at a cursory glance:

- You may want to consider using some `Rectangle`, `Size`, and `Point` structures to encapsulate sets of `x/y` and `width/height`. For example, `void AddCard(int index, int column, Size size)`. I also recommend **against** shortening names of variables. Use `column` instead of `col`, it'll pay you dividends in the end.
- Be careful using `+` operator for `string` concatenation. For this example, it may be acceptable for readability, however if you find yourself concatenating several strings use `string.Format(...)` instead. If you need to build a string dynamically, use `StringBuilder` and the `Append` methods, and finally `ToString()`. Also consider moving this logic for building the name to the factory/constructor.
- Furthermore, avoid using inline string constants, instead make constant variables elsewhere, such as `static readonly string QuestItemCardName = "QuestItemCard"` and use that. This will help reduce typos and also allow you to refactor it in just one place if need be in the future.
- Use the `var` keyword (if your .NET version allows). For example, `var gameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(...)`. This allows your code to be less verbose and also gives you some flexibility when refactoring. Let the compiler do the type inferencing for you.
- Create generic factory methods for your object classes. It looks like your `GameObject` has one called `Instantiate()`. You should change it to `Instantiate<T>(...)` instead, which will remove the need to cast the return value. Combined with `var` this will be a lot neater code.

As for the geometry math, hopefully someone else can chime in here.

UPDATE: Just changes I would make listed above, given assumptions of the OP's code:

```
struct Point
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}

struct Size
{
    public float Width { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
}

struct Rectangle
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
}

private Point origin; // startX/Y
private Point position; // posX/Y
private Size previousSize; // previousWidth/Height

private int index = 0;
private int currentColumn;

private static readonly string QuestItemCardPrefix = "QuestItemCard";

private void AddCard(int index, int column, Size size)
{
    var card = GameObject.Instantiate(pfCard00);
    var cardSprite = card.GetComponentInChildren<PackedSprite>();

    card.name = QuestItemCardPrefix + index.ToString();
    card.transform.parent = goCardContainer.transform;
    cardSprite.height = size.Height;

    if (currentColumn != column) 
    {
        position.X += width;

        position.Y = 0;
        previousSize.Height = 0;
    }

    // placement
    position.Y += (previousSize.Height / 2) + (size.Height / 2);
    card.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(origin.X + position.X, origin.Y - position.Y, card.transform.position.z);

    if (currentColumn != column)
    {
        previousSize.Width = size.width;

        currentColumn = column;
    }

    previousSize.Height = size.height;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `String.Format` just to concat two strings?  That's *obfuscating* the intent of the code, not clarifying it.

Comment: You are probably right in this particular instance. I'll update my bullet accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how the above code would be written using everything you listed?

Comment: It depends on what you need to pass. In most cases, when you pass an `X` value, you're also passing a `Y` value to go with it. Same for `width` and `height`. Often times it's best to pass them as a `Rectangle` which has a location `Point` and a `Size`.

As for your instantiation method, it depends on what you are doing inside of that.

I'll copy/paste your code and implement the changes I listed to the best I can assume.

Comment: It's kind of you to answer, but it doesn't seem appropriate to have answered this without knowing Unity's API.

Comment: I disagree. Most of his refactoring would be fairly general use of common patterns found everywhere in C#. Using structures/classes instead of individual fields, better variable naming, factoring out magic numbers/strings, and using factory patterns are all quite common. Even still, you can build easy-to-use wrappers around Unity if need be.